# How to get static range for X axis (Range axis) in JFreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using Jfreechart in one of my projects. I have a peculiar problem with line chart. On X axis we have time as unit
I want to have static range for lets say for 300 secs and after that it should switch into autorange mode. How to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok that was pretty simple enough.

```
domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
domainAxis.setRange(0,300);
```

Comment: How do I add interval between the range? I need the range to display numbers like 0,5,10,15,....,300.